# Form data isn't submitting to database in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

In my home page in my Laravel project I have a modal which contains a form.

```html
<form id="profilesubmitform" method="POST" action="/profilesubmit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="bio" placeholder="Enter your bio here">
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Tell us about yourself!</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profileurl" placeholder="Website/Link">
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Add your site, Carrd, Youtube channel, anything!</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And of course in my **web.php** file I've made a route like so:

```php
Route::post('/profilesubmit', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController@profileSubmit');
```

It's referring to the function in my ProfilesController that should take the data from the form and save it to my database.

```php
public function profileSubmit(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->bio = $request->bio;
    $user->profileurl = $request->profileurl;

    $user->save();

    return redirect('home');
}
}
```

The `$user` variable should be getting the authenticated (logged in) user in the database. The purpose of this all is that so they can submit a bio and URL that will eventually be put on their profile but for now It's just being put into the 'bio' and 'profileurl' columns in the table.

However when I submit the form it adds nothing. Notably, it's saying that "save()" is an undefined method which is odd because it only gets caught as an error when I define $user as "Auth::user();". Any help?

Comment: Read about the `name` attribute

Comment: You can write the code inside the model

Comment: That's a little vague. What about that attribute..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `name` attribute for each `<input/>`

> Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed
> when submitting a form.

Also add `{{ csrf_field() }}` for AntiCSRF

here I've rewritten your code.

```
<form id="profilesubmitform" method="POST" action="/profilesubmit">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <input type="textarea" id="bio" name="bio" placeholder="Enter your bio here">
        <small>Tell us about yourself!</small>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="profileurl" name="profileUrl" placeholder="Website/Link">
        <small>Add your site, Carrd, Youtube channel, anything!</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm getting an integrity constraint violation error after submitting with this new code. I thought it might just be 'cause of csrf but I added that bit too.